# If $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, and $I(A)$ is an indicator random variable, what is the pdf of $I(A)*X$?

Tags: probability, statistics

If $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, and $I(A)$ is an indicator random variable, what is the pdf of $I(A)\cdot X$? I know that the pdf of the normal but know that the indicator random variable has a pdf in the weak sense, but don't know where to go because the convolution will not work. Does anyone have any hints? thanks!

Comment: Unless $A$ is an almost sure event, $P(I(A)\cdot X=0)>0$, which cannot happen to a variable with pdf. So there is no pdf.

Comment: As an aside, does the fact there is no pdf directly imply that $I(A)*X$ is not a normal distribution? Since there is essentially a discontinuity at zero? Thanks!

Comment: Normal distribution has a pdf. This distribution has no pdf (you can explain this by saying that the cdf is discontinuous at zero, correct). So it is not normal.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "you can explain this by saying the cdf is discontinuous at zero", is this based on the fact that the support on this r.v. is $[0, \infty)$ and so by the definition of a cdf, we must have that $lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x) = lim_{x \to 0} F(x) = 0$ (as this case is not)? Would it also equally suffice to argue that the probability of a point in a continuous distribution is 0, and hence it is not continuous, it cant be normal? (which is what i think is above) thanks and sorry for the long winded response.

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence. *Would it also equally suffice to argue that the probability of a point in a continuous distribution is 0, and hence it is not continuous, it cant be normal?* Yes.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I had meant to put multiply, instead of convolution.

Comment: Do you actually want the distribution (not pdf) of this "mixed" (discrete and continuous) random variable or do you just want to be able to say that it's not normal?

Answer (score 1):

I confess that after all the Comments the question is still not
clear to me. Below I have simulated (in R) what I $suppose$ to be a
relevant experiment a million times. My event $A$ has probability 1/2.
For the normal distribution $\mu = 5$ and $\sigma=10.$

```
 m = 10^6;  mu = 5;  sg = 10
 x = sample(c(0,1), m, rep=T) * rnorm(m, mu, sg)
 mean(x);  sd(x)
 ## 2.506498   # approx. E(X) to about two places
 ## 7.502931   # approx. SD(X) "
 plot.ecdf(x[0:10000], pch=20, ylab="CDF", xlab="x",
    main="Empirical CDF: 10,000 Realizations of X")
```

The empirical CDF of the first 10,000 realizations of $X$
gives a good idea of its theoretical CDF. (Notice that the
two 'pieces' are NOT symmetrical.)

[image]

If this is indeed relevant, it should help you towards a solution.
If not, maybe it will help you to edit the question so your intent
is clear.